# SQL Using CASE with criteria stored as a value in another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm hoping that I'm overlooking something really simple with my issue. I have a fee calculation query that I need to write that utilizes rules in many tables to calculate.  One of the tables defines the conditions for which a particular fee will be applicable. I was hoping to avoid dynamic SQL but if it will be required please note that I have a few CTEs that are being used in the master procedure.

I've simplified the stored procedure to the following which illustrates the problem well. I need to have the contents of the [Formula] applied as the Boolean expression in the case statement but I continue to receive the error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'

If you replace the field Formula with the actual contents it works as desired.

```
CREATE TABLE #FeeRule
(
     FeeRuleID INT IDENTITY,
     FeeName NVARCHAR(50),
     FeeRate DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO #FeeRule
    SELECT 'FlatFee', 450.00

CREATE TABLE #FeeCondition
(
     ConditionID INT IDENTITY,
     FeeRuleID INT,
     Formula NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #FeeCondition
    SELECT 1, 'StockType = 1'

CREATE TABLE #Accounts 
(
     ID INT IDENTITY, 
     AcctName NVARCHAR(200), 
     StockType INT
)

INSERT INTO #Accounts
    SELECT 'Account One', 0 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Account Two', 1

SELECT 
    AcctName,
    Fee = CASE 
             WHEN Formula IS NULL
                THEN FeeRate 
             ELSE 
                CASE WHEN Formula -- StockType = 1 --
                        THEN FeeRate
                        ELSE 0 
                END
          END
FROM 
    #Accounts A
JOIN 
    #FeeRule B ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN 
    #FeeCondition C ON C.FeeRuleID = B.FeeRuleID

DROP TABLE #FeeRule
DROP TABLE #FeeCondition
DROP TABLE #Accounts
```

Comment: `Formula` is not a condition expression: it has to be like `Formula = 1`. Furthermore, `'StockType = 1'` is a string not SQL - so it can't be used directly as a condition. This will require "dynamic SQL" or changing how the condition is represented (eg. take a column and value separately and then build those up in conditionals). I recommend a re-validation of the requirements, if possible, as dynamic SQL is tricky and can lead to second-order injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks.  I was suspecting that dynamic sql will be needed.  We are trying to keep business logic out of the code hence the need to reference tables that the business users would be updating for simple conditionals related to the application of the fee rules.

Comment: Can LINQ be used? There are a number of "rules engines", some can target SQL through expression trees. Likewise, it's relatively simply to add refinements to IQueryable's in frameworks like EF.